# Vuetify: How to create new rows based on screen resolution

Tags: vuetify.js

using vuetify here; when the browser hits the *sm* breakpoint i'd like to have one column per row. anything *md* or above will have two columns per row -- as shown below. it's not clear from the documentation on how this is done. my code below works fine in *md* and above, but it still keeps both columns in one row for *sm*. how can i get it to wrap to a new row then?

```
<v-container fluid>
        <v-row>
          <v-col sm="12" md="6">
            <v-card>
              1A
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
          <v-col sm="12" md="6">
            <v-card>
              1B
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-col sm="12" md="6">
            <v-card>
              2A
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
          <v-col sm="12" md="6">
            <v-card>
              2B
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-col sm="12" md="6">
            <v-card>
              3A
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
          <v-col sm="12" md="6">
            <v-card>
              3B
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-col sm="12" md="6">
            <v-card>
              4A
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
          <v-col sm="12" md="6">
            <v-card>
              4B
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-col sm="12" md="6">
            <v-card>
              5A
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
          <v-col sm="12" md="6">
            <v-card>
              5B
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
```

Comment: And what's the problem? The code doesn't work or what?

Comment: Apologies, I just updated the post.  When it's in "sm" breakpoint and smaller I only want one card per row.

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#breakpoint-service sm is 600px > < 960px. Don't you mean xs maybe? Because it looks ok to me. Plus you can use cols="12" (I don't know why it is not on the doc page here) which would set default value to all breakpoints but those you specify.

Comment: I just realized you need colon in front of the props... :md="6" . I am not sure if it works without those. You should install Vue Devtools to your browser so you see eventual errors.

Comment: @digitalniweb - thank you, you were right on target and it works great. the default :cols="12" and a :md="6" is just what i needed. thank you so much.